# jQuery if statments for long list or?

Tags: jquery

I have link around 15 images. Each image has a title and alt tag. When clicked each image shows another image and description that is associated with the image that was clicked. I am currently doing this and it works. It shows the correct description in the div #me-dsc and the image in #me-give but im wondering if there is a better way, rather than using 15 if statements?

```
$('a.linkhover').on('click',function (event){
    event.preventDefault();    
    var titleTxt = $(this).find('img').attr('title');

    if (titleTxt == 'Pies')
    {
        $('#me-dsc').html('Shoes');
        $('#me-give').html('<img src="assets/images/shoes.svg" alt="'+ titleTxt +'" >');
    }

    else if (titleTxt == 'Car')
    {
        $('#me-dsc').html('Car');
        $('#me-give').html('<img src="assets/images/car.svg" alt="'+ titleTxt +'" >');
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there any logical connection between the pictures, or do you have to know which picture fits to another? For the second case, a switch might be the better choice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store the descriptions, title text and image sources in the `<a>` element where you want the click event to be triggered from, using HTML5's `data-` attributes. For example:

```
<a href="#" class="linkhover" title="Pies" data-desc="Shoes" data-img-src="shoes.svg">Pies</a>
<a href="#" class="linkhover" title="Car" data-desc="Car" data-img-src="car.svg">Car</a>
```

For your jQuery, it's rather straightforward:

```
$('a.linkhover').on('click', function (event){ 
    // Prevent default action
    event.preventDefault();

    // Cache $(this)
    var $this = $(this),
        title = $this.attr('title'),
        desc = $this.attr('data-desc'),
        imgSrc = $this.attr('data-img-src');

    // Set HTML
    $('#me-dsc').html(desc);
    $('#me-give').html('<img src="assets/images/'+imgSrc+'" alt="'+title+'" >');
});
```

See proof-of-concept fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/da2ubvs0/3/

---

For the sake of completeness, you can also try constructing an image object in jQuery instead of using plain HTML:

```
var $img = $('<img />', {
    'src': 'assets/images/'+imgSrc,
    'alt': title
});
$('#me-give').html($img);
```

Works just as fine ;) http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/da2ubvs0/4/

Comment: Nice Terry. Thanks. That works and is much better than all the if else statements! Rob

Comment: Any issues with using data-desc and data-img-src in older browsers?

Comment: @Rob I don't think so: http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset. Even IE8 has partial support (not accessible using `dataset`, but possible through `getAttribute`), which I think is covered by jQuery :)